# Multiple jQuery autocomplete in one page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

## UPDATE

I checked the dropdown elements and it seems that the succeeding dropdown elements are not populated by the

```
    .data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( 
              '<a class="select-group"><span class="mini-headtitle">' + item.institution_name + 
              '</span><br/><span class="mini-subtitle">' + item.municipality + '</span></a>' )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
}
```

part. **But the "missing" elements still has the items needed! How do I solve this?**

## PROBLEM

I have dynamically added textboxes which correspond to a jQuery Autocomplete script. 
Whenever a new textbox is added to the DOM, it should also have the same autocomplete from the first.

**Autocomplete works on all newly added DOM textboxes but only the first instance has its select box filled with options.**

### First textbox

[image]

### Succeeding textboxes

[image]

My textboxes have the id `InstitutionName[1]` where the number grows as more elements are added.

I use the code below:

```
function ajax_connect_to_db()
{
    $('input[id^="InstitutionName"]')
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: "new_account/get_institution_info_db",
      dataType: "json",
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $( this ).val( ui.item.institution_name );
          return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        // get unique textbox number inside brackets
        var str = $(this).attr('id');
        var pos = str.indexOf("[") + 1;
        var index = str.slice(pos, str.lastIndexOf("]"));

        // fill in the respective textboxes
        $(this).val( ui.item.institution_name );
        $( 'input[id="InstitutionID['+ index +']"]' ).val( ui.item.id );
        $( 'input[id="InstitutionMunicipality['+ index +']"]' ).val( ui.item.municipality );
        $( 'input[id="InstitutionProvince['+ index +']"]' ).val( ui.item.province );
        return false;
      }
    })
    .data( 'ui-autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( 
              '<a class="select-group"><span class="mini-headtitle">' + item.institution_name + 
              '</span><br/><span class="mini-subtitle">' + item.municipality + '</span></a>' )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
}  

// target newly added DOM textboxes
setInterval( ajax_connect_to_db, 100 );
```

**How do I make the select box show its content on all dynamically added elements?**

Comment: try to use class name

Comment: I tried it in the `.data( 'ui-autocomplete' )` part but it still does not work. I used `.data( $('ul[class^="ui-autocomplete"]') )`.

Comment: `InstitutionName[1]` is not a valid `id`. `id`s must be a valid [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), this means only using `a-zA-Z0-9`, `_`, `-` and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher. In order to use ISO 10646 characters below U+00A0, like `[` and `]` you need to escape them: `\[` and `\]` or `\5B` and `\5D`. You might have better luck with `InstitutionName\[1\]`. It might be sort of working as is, but it really shouldn't be. Instead of putting the number in brackets, I'd just separate it with a dash: `InstitutionName-1`, it's valid and cleaner IMO.

Comment: @UselessCode, thank you very much for that information. I'll definitely use that in my future projects. 
The one I have is nearing its completion so I think it's not convenient to change my form fields' id's. I wish I knew that sooner!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function ajax_connect_to_db()
{

$(function() {

   .................
});

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Still no changes though.